# Rails Controller is ignoring queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm creating a simple upvote/downvote system similar to reddit's, where users can upvote/downvote something and change their minds if need be.

I have a page that makes an AJAX call to the 'create' action of my controller. The controller has no problem creating the record and returning the proper js.erb. However, I'd like to see if an existing post exists, and if so, I'd like to destroy it. My controller looks like this:

```
def create
    @vote = GameVote.new
    @vote.game_id = params[:game_id]
    @vote.vote = params[:vote]
    @vote.user_id = session[:user_id]

    existing_vote = GameVote.where(whatever)

 respond_to do |format|
   if @vote.save
    format.js
   end
  end
end
```

It just seems to ignore the middle query, preventing me from destroying it if it exists before attempting to save the new entry. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question exactly? How to find an existing vote? How to delete it? It's very unclear what the problem is from the code you are showing.

Comment: Hey @Mischa - The existing_vote = GameVote.where(whatever) doesn't get fired. Within the server console, I don't see the query being run, and I can't figure out why. With proper arguments, it runs fine in the rails console, but the controller just seems to ignore it in practice. I'm wondering why that is.

Comment: This is because Rails only executes the query when it's needed. You don't do anything with `existing_vote`, so no query is executed. It's built-in optimization in Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems more natural to update the existing GameVote (if one exists) instead of pair delete+create.

To do so just replace:

```
@vote = GameVote.new
@vote.game_id = params[:game_id]
@vote.vote = params[:vote]
@vote.user_id = session[:user_id]

existing_vote = GameVote.where(whatever)
```

with:

```
@vote = GameVote.where(game_id: params[:game_id], user_id: session[:user_id]).first_or_initialize
@vote.vote = params[:vote]
```

Comment: Hey @jdoe, the code you pasted threw an undefined_method error. (NoMethodError (undefined method `first_or_initialize' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation):) -- I'd like to update as opposed to destroying. Is there an elegant way to do this within the same method?

Comment: `first_or_initialize` is the Rails 3.2 feature. But you can still use find_or_initialize_by_* approach. You didn't specify your Rails version so I couldn't answer more precise.

Comment: Hey @jdoe - I just upgraded to rails 3.2 from 3.1, but I'm still getting the same error. Thanks for your help so far - hopefully I get it soon.

Comment: She's rollin'. Thank you muchly!

Comment: What was the problem? Did you forget to update you Gemfile? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
@vote = GameVote.find_or_create_by_game_id_and_user_id(params[:game_id], session[:user_id])
OR
@vote = GameVote.find_or_create(:game_id => params[:game_id], :user_id => session[:user_id])

@vote.vote = params[:vote]
```

Comment: Hey @Vik, those are also throwing undefined_method errors. I'm using Rails 3.1.0 - should I upgrade?

Comment: This method available in rails 3.0.9 , 3.2+

Comment: I'd select yours as the answer as well, if I was able! Many thanks!